# Travelling to NZ on visa-waiver while WHV Transfer is pending

Tags: visa-free-entry, new-zealand, working-holiday

A little background: I received the Working Holiday Visa last year in December, but renewed my passport in January and forgot all about it until earlier this week. I rushed to submit a visa transfer application 3 days ago and since INZ said that the transfer generally takes 11-20 days, I included a cover letter explaining the situation with my air tickets.

I am flying in 3 days and there has been no news. I am from a Visa-waiver country and therefore shouldn't have problems going into NZ without a visa, but I am worried about the Visa being cancelled because I am on NZ soil, or because Visa-waiver counts as a visa or something.

My question is, should I come clean at the Customs with an immigration officer or just go through the e-gate under visa-waiver? I am worried about being denied entry if I come clean, but I do have my old passport and emails stating that my work will only begin on 20th March (more than enough time for transfer to be done). I will only be sightseeing for the first 2 weeks. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [FAQ](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/knowledgebase/kb-question/kb-question-5746) implies that the WHV is valid and you try to enter on a visitor visa instead which is not what you want to do. I'm not sure I'd chance it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following quote from [I have a Working Holiday Visa but want to enter New Zealand as a visitor](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/knowledgebase/kb-question/kb-question-5746) explains your situation quite clearly (emphasis mine):

> If you insist on entering New Zealand as a visitor instead, your Working Holiday visa **will automatically be cancelled** if you are issued a Visitor Visa at the border however not everyone is eligible for this and you could be refused entry.

Because you have a different passport number than when you originally were granted your WHV, it is possible that this *may* not happen automatically. However, they *will* catch up to you when you try to transfer your WHV and they realise what you have done and would not hesitate to cancel your WHV manually.

Comment: If I just show up at immigration and explain my situation with both my passports and the relevant documents, will I be able to get through? It says on the INZ website that you will be "delayed" if you have the e-visa tagged to a different passport, but does that include being denied entry?

Comment: @user92903: You *might* be able to sort it out on entry. I would phone INZ directly and ask whether you can do that in your situation. The fact is, *you* have been granted a WHV, so technically it should be possible. As they say, expect delays. I would not necessarily expect to be denied entry.

Comment: Oh, the other thing you will want to consider is whether the *airline* will accept your documentation and allow you to board the plane in the first place. Because you are (probably) planning to spend more than 3 months in NZ, you won't have a return flight booked within that time, which will raise flags in their system for an NZ *visitor*, unless you can convince them that you will actually be entering NZ with a WHV.

Comment: I see. I wouldn't mind delays; just afraid of being denied entry. I am also only staying for slightly less than 3 months due to personal reasons, and have accommodation and the return ticket all booked. I am also curious about the wording on this page:

https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/travelling-to-and-arriving-in-new-zealand

which says that if your passport is different, you must "apply to transfer" before you fly, instead of "must be transferred" before you fly. I am kinda banking on this at this point.